# Как сделать, что бы один объект был виден в нескольких формах?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, ооп, visual-studio

У моего приложения есть две формы, и один класс с описанием логики, хранящий данные приложения. Когда я создаю в классе одной из форм объект класса логики, то он становится не видим в другой форме... 
**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как объявить объект класса логики, что бы он был виден во всех формах?**

В принципе, я понимаю, что можно объявить объект в одной из форм, и потом передавать его от туда во все остальные, но не будет ли это накладно для ресурсов? Правильно ли это?

Языка С# winforms

Comment: что значит "как объявить"? Дайте ему модификатор **public** и сможете пользоваться из всех классов, которые имеют доступ к сборке, где объявлен этот класс.

Comment: Отделяйте контент от представления. Передавайте различным view один и тот же контент, пусть они строят, где надо, одинаковое представление (сделайте разделяемую процедуру построения представления).

Comment: Если проект маленький и неинтересный, то проще будет завести static класс, а в нём Вашу static переменную.
Если проект побольше и поинтересней, юзайте ioc и иже с ним.

Answer (score 2):

Лучше создать объект вне классов форм, но чтобы форму друг другу передавали ссылку на этот объект. Тогда у вас и цель будет достигнута, и сборщик мусора будет спокойно уничтожать ненужные экземпляры форм.

Answer (score 0):

Это инкапсуляция, так и должно быть.

Можно ссылку на необходимый объект данных передавать в Main через конструкторы объектов форм. Ну или через публичные свойства форм, имея ссылкии между ними.